# Controlling the amount of space-evenly to fill space

Tags: css, react-native, styled-components, styling

I'm creating a vertical container with 4 icons inside. This Icons will be spaced evenly, but I wan't to be able to "Control" the amount of space-evenly of the items. Now the icons are not filling all the container.
As you can see in the right with the black opacity container, the icons are evenly spaced but not fully filling the container (Black opacity area) I want to fully fill the container with the space-evenly

[image]

My Styles:

```
        <InteractionContainer>
          <Touchable>
            <HeartIcon />
          </Touchable>

          <Touchable>
            <CommentsIcon />
          </Touchable>

          <Touchable>
            <SendIcon />
          </Touchable>

          <Touchable>
            <MoreIcon />
          </Touchable>
        </InteractionContainer>
      </WrapperContainer>
    </Container>
  );
}


export const InteractionContainer = styled.View`
  height: 228px;
  width: 45px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
`;
```

I want to make the icons touch the top of the circulated red part.

Comment: you can try space-around or space-between if that what you mean

Comment: I want to space-between like I'm doing, but I want to fill the space in the end of the container, I have updated the image

Comment: So all I can say is apply space-between, however if it's not bringing the desired output than  inspect the size of icon( for better understanding blue areal covers by icon while inspecting from google chrome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
justify-content: space-evenly;
```

to

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

if there is some black still exiting make sure the padding is set to O

```
padding: O;
```